# Chess AI: MinMax on object implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, chess

I'm writing an AI for a game similar to chess.
The board is 10x10 with 15 pieces for each side
which all have chess similar moves.

Everything in the game is organized in objects.
Tile[][] tiles; 10x10, every Tile has a piece-pointer to a piece or null.

I've implemented a MinMax algorithm with no pruning so far.
Possible moves each round are on average twice as many as in a chess game.

The algorithm works but it's very slow. On average it can check 
40000 moves/pr sec. So with a depth of 4 my game uses around 4-5 seconds to
calculate all possible moves. I will implement pruning later, but could need
some feedback on my implementation first.

**Question:
Do i have to convert to char-arrays/bit-board or similar to speed up the 
calculation or am i doing something horribly wrong?**

Implementation: (sudo)
To avoid lots of double for-loops i keep track of myPieces and opponentPieces
in Lists of Tiles. Board evaluation is also done once and then only updates 
and only updated by adding and subtracting the value of a move.
In my implementation of the minMax algorithm i use a GameState class that
holds the current gameState.

```
GameState {
 Tile[][] board
 List<Tile> myPieces;
 List<Tile> otherPieces;
 int[][] evaluatedBoard
 int evaluatedValue
 Piece moveFrom, moveTo //used to save pointer when applying move
 int moveFromValue, moveToValue //used to save evaluationValue when applying move


 void applyMove(Tile from, Tile to)
 void undoMove(Tile from, Tile to)
 GameState createCopy()
}
```

ApplyMove only updates the evaluatedValue and does not go through
 the whole array.myPieces and otherPieces are also updated by apply/undo.

MinMax:

```
maxMove(GameState state, int depth) {
 for(Tile from : state.getMyPieces().clone()) { //list will be changed
   for(Tile to : from.getPiece().getPossibleMoves()) {
       if(depth == 0)
         //find best move and so forth
       else {
        state.applyMove(from, to);
        minMove(state.createCopy(), depth - 1) //similar to maxMove except it uses otherPieces
        state.undoMove(from, to)
       }
   }
 }
 //return best move
}
```

Edit:
Added information about applyMove and Profiler

```
Profiler:          instructions
applyMove()     3200ms  11 430 000 
undoMove()      1800ms  11 430 000
evaluateTile()  1400ms  22 400 000
minMove()       1700ms  315 493
```

applyMove and undoMove only store/reverse pointers to the old
value off from and to and replace them with the new ones from
the move. Then calls evaluateTile which returns a number from 1-10
depending on a enum Type in piece.

Comment: I think you need to get a profiler out to see exactly ***what part*** is slow. From the above code, it may be the `getPossibleMoves()` function or the board _evaluation function_ which you didn't show

Comment: Looks OK, but you seem to have a lot of unnecessary indirections and copies.  I don't think you need to `state.getMyPieces().clone()`, since any pieces that are removed by a deeper recursion level will be replaced by it before it returns (using `undoMove()`), and likewise for `state.createCopy()`.

Comment: The reason why i'm using createCopy() is because the prevValue holders are stored in the state. If i didn't create a copy i wouldn't be able to undoMove. I could move them out of the state-object, but would that really save me a lot of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice of representation is going to cost you a great deal - every move you consider requires you to copy a lot of state.  The way I see it, you have two choices:

(1) make your state representation very small (in chess you can do this in 64 x 4 bits, or 4 Int64s in .NET) so copying it is very cheap; or

(2) make your state representation immutable with deltas, so creating an updated state is  cheap.

I'd try option (1) first and see how you go.

Here's some links you may find useful: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_representation_(chess)
http://www.cis.uab.edu/hyatt/boardrep.html

Comment: Or "(3) Use mutable state, but make all moves quickly undoable", which appears to be what s/he's doing without realising that this avoids the need to make copies!

Comment: I do realise it, however since i'm using an iterator changing the list will throw a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. If I used get(i) instead it would be hard to keep track off which elements I've already checked. I will try to figure out another way to do this.

Comment: @Bendik - your comment suggests you aren't very aware of the constant factors involved in things like iterators.  Seriously, if you want performance, your representation needs to be just an array of numbers which you access directly by index.  Build your abstraction atop that and you should notice a huge speed increase.